# Intellij IDEA:How to copy wrong hint?

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to copy the hint in the picture, what should I do?

[image]

Comment: One option would be to take a screen capture of your IntelliJ, then paste in Paint and manually transcript the text you see.  This is usually how I go about doing it.  There may be a log somewhere which also contains this text, if it were generated from a compile or build.

Answer (score 0):

The hints provided by IntelliJ in the editor are generally the same messages you'd see if you compiled the project.  So, you can either:

- compile the class, or
- attempt to run your `main` method, which would attempt to compile this class

in order to copy the error message.

If the code *does* compile successfully, then a screenshot is your only option, as the tooltip text cannot be freely copied.